# Are push and pop operation for hashes and arrays atomic and thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, hash, push, semaphore, raku

I have a huge data file (close to 4T) that I need to crunch. I am using 4 threads on my 4-core CPU. First thread analyzes the first quarter of the file, and so on. All the threads need to add their results to the same single hash and single array after they have analyzed sections of their own quarter of the data file. So, is the "push" and "pop" and "shift" and "unshift" operations for hash and array atomic and thread-safe, or I have to resort to more complicated mechanisms like semaphores?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they are neither atomic nor threadsafe, and use from multiple threads will lead to crashes or data inconsistencies.

That said, even if they were, a design that involves lots of contention on the same data structure will scale poorly as you add more threads. This is because of the way hardware works in the face of parallelism; briefly:

- Memory performance is heavily dependent on caches
- Some cache levels are per CPU core
- Writing to memory means getting it exclusively into the current core's cache
- The process of moving it from one core's cache in order to write to it is costly (ballpack 60-100 cycle penalty)

You can use locking to attain *correctness*. For this, I don't recommend working with a lock directly, but instead look in to a module like `OO::Monitors`, where you can encapsulate the hash in an object and have locking done at the boundaries.

If the number of pushes you do on the shared data structure is low compared to the amount of work done to produce the items to push, then you might not bottleneck on the locking and contention around the data structure. If you are doing thousands of `push`es or similar per second, however, I suggest looking for an alternative design. For example:

1. Break the work up into a part for each worker
2. Use `start` to set off each worker, which returns a `Promise`. Put the `Promise`s into an array.
3. Have each `Promise` return an array or hash of the items that it produced.
4. Merge the results from each one. For example, if each returns an array, then `my @all-results = flat await @promises;` or similar is enough to gather all of the results together.

You might find your problem fits well into the [parallel iterator paradigm, using hyper or race](https://docs.raku.org/routine/hyper), in which case you don't even need to break up the work or set up the workers yourself; instead, you can pick a degree and batch size.

Comment: Ironically I think I inappropriately caused dataloss by doing a concurrent edit that overwrote one or more edits you made. (I didn't know it could happen, but on reflection it makes sense. I've learned the lesson that I should either just comment, or wait until long after someone's answered. Probably that's obvious to others *before* they make such a mistake. Sorry about my undue eagerness.) Anyhow,, by reading the original, and then the diff between them, I hope to have reduced the dataloss. I'll now leave well alone. Again, sorry, and I won't make an undue eagerness mistake like this again.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonathan Worthington and raiph !!! I now will have to do some tweaking of my code with your suggestions. Thanks !

Comment: On a second thought, if 2 threads are trying to push data to the same hash and the push operation is not atomic and not thread safe, does it mean that, for example, thread 1 pushes the key and half of the value, and thread 2 pushes its key and 3/4 of its value, and then thread 1 pushes the second half of its value, and then thread 2 pushed the last 1/4 of its value? I am trying to test it out.